# Space complexity of comma swap in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was writing a code to rotate an array by k places in-place (i.e *O(1)* space complexity)

```
nums[n-k:],nums[:n-k] = nums[:n-k], nums[n-k:]
```

Will the above code take *O(1)* or *O(n)* space internally?

I know `a,b = b,a` uses an extra variable for swapping internally. Will the list swap operation use extra space in *O(n)* or is there any optimization done internally?

Comment: The slicing you're doing will take O(n) space complexity. The comma swap is negligible.

Comment: @khelwood thanks. Was working in leetcode and this was one of the top solutions so was wondering if I was missing a trick